# Spring-cloud-consul backward compatibility of property value parsing for "spring.cloud.consul.host" broken in spring-cloud-consul version 3.1.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

After upgrading my spring-boot application that uses Consul, I observe backward compatibility is broken. Spring boot upgraded from `spring-boot:2.1.4.RELEASE` to `spring-boot:jar:2.7.3`.

Earlier spring-cloud-consul used to work with bootstrap property "spring.cloud.consul.host" which contained value that included port also, eg: https://xyz:8610, now spring-cloud is forcing user to set additional property "spring.cloud.consul.port", if not forcefully appending consul default port, ending in invalid URI like https://<xyz.com>:8610:8500/v1/kv/abc/services

(spring-boot/spring-cloud) from

Spring-cloud-consul backward compatibility of property value parsing for "spring.cloud.consul.host" broken in `spring-cloud-consul` version 3.1.1 in spring-boot application version `spring-boot:jar:2.7.3`. It was working fine in older `spring-cloud-consul-core:jar:2.1.1`

As our application internally has addition custom usage in using host:port specified in one single property this is breaking upgrade.

Could someone confirm if spring-cloud is Mandating this change.

Error Details:

```
[ERROR] 2023-01-08 16:12:33,644 [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication Application run failed
org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySources$PropertySourceNotFoundException: com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: https://<xyz.com>:8610:8500/v1/kv/abc/services/xyz-service/?recurse&token=yyy-xxx
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySources.createPropertySource(ConsulPropertySources.java:143)
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate(ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:51)
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java:71)
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b35ebf8.invoke(<generated>)

...

Caused by: com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: https://rn-spindlet-lapp21.rno.apple.com:8610:8500/v1/kv/rins/services/file-service,aluminum-prod-logging/?recurse&token=e23d8856-cfb3-2d2e-6fd2-e2ed3ab6f341
    at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.executeRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:83)
    at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.makeGetRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:36)
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulRawClient.makeGetRequest(ConsulRawClient.java:139)
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulRawClient.makeGetRequest(ConsulRawClient.java:128)
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.kv.KeyValueConsulClient.getKVValues(KeyValueConsulClient.java:147)
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient.getKVValues(ConsulClient.java:644)
```

My bootstrap:

```
spring:
   cloud:
      consul:
         config:
            format: YAML
            data-key: local
            enabled: true
            prefix: abc/services
         host: https://xyz:8610
         token: xxx
         tls:
            keyStoreInstanceType: PKCS12
            certificatePath: /abc/keystore
            certificatePassword: rrr
            keyStorePath: /abc/keystore
            keyStorePassword: rrr
```

Actual result: ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: https://<xyz.com>:8610:8500/v1/kv/abc/services/

Expect: Spring cloud should initialize bootstrap currently as it was working fine in older `spring-cloud-consul-core:jar:2.1.1`. This compatibility broken in higher `spring-cloud-consul-core:jar:3.1.1`

Comment: There was a major release, so breaking changes are allowed. There is a `spring.cloud.consul.port` property to go along with the host.

Comment: yeah but is there documentation that it has been made mandatory? our app has internal customization initializing application based on parsing single property spring.cloud.consul.host which was earlier allowed to contain host:port using : as seperator. Any workaround? as we have too many apps running on earlier premise we are impacted.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is related to [Config File Processing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#config-file-processing-application-properties-and-yaml-files) changes in Spring Boot 2.4.

As result

> Bootstrap has been disabled by default. The new way of importing configuration is via the new spring.config.import functionality provided by Spring Boot 2.4. Please see the appropriate documentation for Config Client, Consul, Vault, and Zookeeper for details on how to use them with the new config import.

https://spring.io/blog/2020/12/22/spring-cloud-2020-0-0-aka-ilford-is-available

If you require the legacy bootstrap functionality add the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` dependency to your project or migrate to new ConfigData API.